# TYPO3 Symfony Expression: isset() for Query Parameters?

Tags: symfony, typo3, typoscript

I am using several Symfony expressions in my TypoScript checking for query parameters such as this:

```
[request.getQueryParams()['tx_news_pi1']['news'] > 0]
do something
[END]
```

This is working well – as long as the query parameter exists. If it doesn’t, the following error message is written into the log file:

```
Unable to get an item on a non-array.
```

In PHP I would use `isset()` to check whether the query parameter exists – but I could not find a similar way for Symfony expressions in TypoScript. I have tried

```
[request.getQueryParams()['tx_news_pi1']['news']]
```

which works the same, meaning: it does what it’s supposed to do, but logs an error message if the query parameter does not exist.

Is there anything like `isset()` for the Symfony Expression Language in TYPO3?

Answer (score 4):

The `is_defined()` or `isset()` I was looking for will be returned by the condition

```
[request.getQueryParams()['tx_news_pi1']]
```

instead of

```
[request.getQueryParams()['tx_news_pi1']['news']]
```

In my use case this would even be enough. If you need to be more precise *(e.g. to differentiate between different query parameters within the same plugin),* go for

```
[request.getQueryParams()['tx_news_pi1'] && request.getQueryParams()['tx_news_pi1']['news'] > 0]
```

The solution was provided as a reply to a [bug report on forge.typo3.org](https://forge.typo3.org/issues/88756#change-404466)

Comment: as long as the official documentation remains a bit outdated, one can find a good overview of available expressions here:
https://www.nitsan.in/blog/all-you-need-to-know-about-typoscript-conditions-with-symfony-expression-language/

Comment: Thanks for the hint ! My Logfile was full of that error with a laaaarge stacktrace....

Answer (score 0):

in newer TYPO3 versions:

```
[traverse(request.getQueryParams(), 'tx_news_pi1/news') > 0]
   do something
[END]
```

Answer (score 0):

**How to properly mitigate the issue**

The array path access can be guareded by using the [`traverse()` [1]](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/main/en-us/Conditions/Index.html#traverse) method. However, to guard that the request object is there and therefore the `getQueryParams()` can be called, this needs to be checked too.

For example, this may happen if such conditions are used in the `user TSconfig` or the `page TSconfig`.

A proper solution and a generic snippet pattern in all cases would be:

```
[request && traverse(request.getQueryParams(), 'tx_news_pi1/news') > 0]
```

In newer TYPO3 core versions, or better to say at least with [`symfony/expression-language` [4]](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/expression_language.html#null-coalescing-operator) ^6.1.x the [`null-safe-operator` [2]](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/formats/expression_language.html#null-safe-operator) may be used before calling the object method (which returns null then).

```
[traverse(request?.getQueryParams(), 'tx_news_pi1/news') > 0]
```

With at least [`symfony/expression-language` [4]](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/expression_language.html#null-coalescing-operator) 6.2 we could also use the [`null-coalescing operator` [3]](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/expression_language.html#null-coalescing-operator) equalient combined with the `null-safe-operator`:

```
[request?.getQueryParams()['tx_news_pi1']['news'] ?? 0 > 0]
```

On newer TYPO3 version you have more options due to the newer `symfony/expression-lanuage` version available. As a experienced developer I would personally prefere the latest version if possible, but for integrators it may be better to use the request && traverse() method as a conveniant method to guard this through multiple versions - and maybe being kind of more understandable for new integrators and starters without having deeper PHP development experiences.

All ways are legit if available, therefore I stated all variants.

**But why are checks for the array access are needed now?**

PHP8.0 itself changed things and now handles array key accesses which are not set as invalid and raised the level from simple `notice` to `warnings` which throws more errors.

The [`symfony/expression-language` [4]](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/expression_language.html#null-coalescing-operator) package basically transform to the PHP code which now emits the corresponding warning (or stack trace) depending on the selected mode (production/debug) and the error/exception level reporting settings. Which now may crashes if such TypoScript/(user|page TSconfig) is used.

PHP Developer needed to guard this in PHP code and the TYPO3 core got a couple of (hundreds) patches to guard numberless `array key access` violations through the whole core.

The `traverse()` can help to mitigate this and it's available quite a while and is therefore availble in older TYPO3 versions already so it can prepared in older projects minimizeing it on upgrades.

Since [`symfony/expression-language` [4]](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/expression_language.html#null-coalescing-operator) 6.2 the equalient of the PHP `null coalsce operator (??)` is also available - which non-php developer may not know either.

The `request` object may be not availbe in the TypoScript or TSConfig context and a direct call to a method on a non-exiting object fails. Therefore, an additional guard needs to be added.

Don't access blindly dynamically paths on objects or arrays which may not be available.

**Links**

- [1] `traverse()`: https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/main/en-us/Conditions/Index.html#traverse
- [2] `null-safe operator`: https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/formats/expression_language.html#null-safe-operator
- [3] `null-coalescing operator` https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/expression_language.html#null-coalescing-operator
- [4] `symfony/expression-language` https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/expression_language.html#null-coalescing-operator

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
[request.getQueryParams()['tx_news_pi1']['news'] = ]
  do something
[END]
```

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately that doesn’t work either: `Expression could not be parsed, fallback kicks in. It looks like an old condition with only one equal sign` … but it also doesn’t work with two equal signs.

Comment: it is a single equal sign.. I used it recently in Typo3 8.x to check if a POST var was set in typoscript..and it worked for me

[globalVar = GP:tx_cal_controller|submit = ] 
page.999 = TEXT
....
[global]

Comment: It is not anymore as the [Symfony Expression Language has been introduced to T3v9.4](https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-core/master/en-us/Changelog/9.4/Feature-85829-ImplementSymfonyExpressionLanguageForTypoScriptConditions.html). The error message about “only one equal sign” I had posted, was in the T3 log file.